# OpenJDK 11 missing default localization

Tags: java, localization, openjdk

I have a problem with a Java Swing application I wrote. Since JDK8 there were always standard localization texts for all the Swing components. These were chosen by the locale set in the Java application. However if I start this Application with a runtime higher than 8 (in my case OpenJDK11) there are no default localization texts anymore no matter which locale I set. All the text stays in english.
Are the localization texts really missing in OpenJDK 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
The OpenJDK I downloaded (from the Oracle website) does not include many resourcebundles for different languages, only english, chinese and japanese. I downloaded the AdoptOpenJDK and with this JDK the Swing components got translated again.

Answer (score 1):

From
[Java 11 Locales and Modules](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java11locales-5069639.html#modules):

> In Oracle's JDK 11, only the US English locale data (and its parent
>   locales, including the ROOT locale) are included in the java.base
>   module. Other locale data are included in the jdk.localedata module.
>   By default, all locale data are available in the JDK. Developers can
>   create a smaller run-time image by stripping unneeded locale data by
>   using the jlink command with the “--include-locales” option. For
>   example, if a user wants to limit locale data to English, Japanese,
>   and all Indian locales, the following jlink command option will create
>   the image:
>
> ```
> jlink --add-modules java.base,jdk.localedata --include-locales en,ja,*-IN (other required jlink options are omitted here)
> ```

You may use the `jlink` command as above if you don't want to include the
entire `jdk.localedata`.

Comment: Well I created now a custom JRE with jlink including all locales from jdk.localedata module. But the result is still the same. No matter which locale I set as ´Locale.setDefault()´ all text from Swing components is still in english, like JOptionPane and JFileChooser.

Comment: Have you seen the article [Making Swing Components Locale-Sensitive](http://www.progdoc.de/papers/intSwing/intswing/intswing.html).